# How to Get Unicode data from Azure Devops Git Repository Get Item Rest Api?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, character-encoding, devops, invoke-restmethod

I prepared following request to get a file content from azure devops reop item api. the file content stored in git in UTF-8 format. but the output of rest api is not as expected! how to fix the issue to get content properly as stored in repo?

```
$uri = "http://devserver/defaultcollection/3e100875-e1dc-4aa4-a9d0-0e97af8a1634/_apis/git/repositories/f26ea979-3786-4bca-965e-0481c07ff9a9/items/Notes%2FREADME.md?versionType=Commit&version=26613c4596f233b0f48ea0f407465d941f0a4144&api-version=7.0"
$contentType  = "application/json;charset=utf-8"
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedPAT" }

$fileContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Method Get
```

Output is a Markdown content:

```
Title|Description|WorkItemID|Software|Area|Type|BuildNumber|Date
-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-
Ø±ÙØ¹ Ø§Ø´Ú©Ø§Ù ÙÙØ§ÛØ´ Ø¯Ø§Ø¯Ù ÙØ´Ø¯Ù ÙØ§Ù ÙÙØ§ÛØ´Û ÙØ¯Ø¹ÙÛÙ Ø¯Ø± ØµÙØ­Ù ÙØ´Ø§ÙØ¯Ù Ø¬ÙØ³Ù|this is description|409925|Organizer||Bug|20231206.1|2023-12-06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- **Your `-ContentType` argument has no effect**; to ask the target web service to return a JSON response - *assuming it supports it* - you'll need to:

  - Use an [`Accept`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header field, e.g.

    ```bash
     -Headers @{ Accept = 'application/json'; Authorization = "Basic $encodedPAT" }
    ```
  - Alternatively, *if available*, in the context of a `GET` request, use a query-string parameter to that effect as part of the URL.
- The problem isn't specific to Azure, it is a **general problem with PowerShell's web cmdlets**: As detailed in the next section, ***Windows PowerShell* and *older versions of* [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) mis-decode UTF-8 responses that aren't declared as such in the `Content-Type` field of the response header.** This is **no longer a problem in PowerShell (Core) *7.4+***, which now (consistently) defaults to UTF-8.

To **ensure decoding as UTF-8**, use **[`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)** rather than [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest); the former's output objects have a **[`.RawContentStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.webresponseobject.rawcontentstream)** property that returns a raw byte stream that you can decode with the encoding of choice.

**Applied to your code** (as noted, only required in PowerShell versions 7.3.x and below, including in Windows PowerShell):

```bash
$uri = "http://devserver/defaultcollection/3e100875-e1dc-4aa4-a9d0-0e97af8a1634/_apis/git/repositories/f26ea979-3786-4bca-965e-0481c07ff9a9/items/Notes%2FREADME.md?versionType=Commit&version=26613c4596f233b0f48ea0f407465d941f0a4144&api-version=7.0"
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedPAT" }

$fileContent = 
 [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
   (
     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
   ).RawContentStream.ToArray()
 )
```

Note the use of [`[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) to obtain a UTF-8 encoding, and its [`.GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.GetString) method to convert an array of bytes to a .NET string.

---

##### Background information:

- The **`-ContentType` parameter** describes the media type and, optionally, character encoding of the **body (data) sent *with the request*, not what you'd like to receive *as a response***.

  - Since you're merely performing a `GET` request without using the `-Body` parameter, the `-ContentType` argument is effectively ignored.
  - While a header field *is* generally available that signals to the server what *response* character encoding is desired - [`Accept-Charset`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.3) - it is rarely honored in practice.
    I presume the same applies if you use a `charset` parameter in the context of also requesting specific *media types*, via the [`Accept`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header field.
- It is therefore the **server** that **decides** what **character encoding to encode the *response* with** and, crucially, ***whether or not* to *explicitly indicate* that encoding in the `Content-Type` response-header field**, e.g. `Content-Type: text/markdown; charset=utf-8`

  - Strictly speaking, the media type for Markdown text, `text/markdown` - assuming that it is used in the server's response - *should* contain a `charset` parameter, which PowerShell's web cmdlets *do* honor.
  - In the ***absence* of such a `charset` parameter**, it is therefore the ***default* character encoding** that applies, as used by PowerShell's web cmdlets, [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod).

The **default character encoding** used by the `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlets **depends on the PowerShell *edition* and *version***, as shown in the following table:

| Edition | Version | Default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows PowerShell | up to 5.1, the latest and *last* version | [ISO 88591-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)<sup>[1]</sup> |
| [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) | 7.0 - 7.3.x | ISO 88591-1, *except* for `application/json` *responses*,<sup>[2]</sup> which default to UTF-8 |
| PowerShell (Core) | 7.4 and above | [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) |

- This default encoding not only applies to decoding *responses*, but also to encoding *request* data, namely when you pass a *string* to the `-Body` parameter (you may alternatively pass arbitrary `[byte]` arrays); you can override this with a `charset` parameter in the `-ContentType` argument, e.g.:
  `-ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`
- If, in a given call, the response body gets mis-decoded due to the above-mentioned defaults, you need to manually decode the raw bytes, as shown in the top section.

---

<sup>[1] This encoding is *largely* identical to [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), except that the following characters are *missing*, notably including `€`:

`€ ‚ ƒ „ … † ‡ ˆ ‰ Š ‹ Œ Ž ‘ ’ “ ” • – — ˜ ™ š › œ ž Ÿ`</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that *request* JSON data passed *as a string* to the `-Body` parameter is, curiously, still encoded as ISO 8859-1 by default, an inconsistency that was resolved in v7.4.</sup>

Comment: thanks for detailed descriptions. i found that the response content-type is `application/octet-stream` so i used Invoke-WebRequest and convert it to UTF8 as you mentioned, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Mehdi.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue when calling the `Invoke-RestMethod` request via the PowerShell with the default version `5` on Windows Sever 2022. Having installed [PowerShell 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.4#installing-the-msi-package), the same request displayed the expected content.

[image]

The issue seems not caused by Azure DevOps and irrelevant whether the file content is restored in UTF-8/Markdown content from your Git repo of Azure DevOps. It is caused by the processing UTF-8 in PowerShell.